# Java Web Application is Working fine with apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x86, but not with apache-tomcat-8.5.40-windows-x86

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I have a Java web application which is deployed in windows server 2008 32 bit machine and it is  working fine with apache-tomcat-8.5.34-windows-x86. The same web application doesn't work with updated version of tomcat i.e., apache-tomcat-8.5.40-windows-x86.

I have gone through several forums, but I haven't found any details, if tomcat apache-tomcat-8.5.40 does support windows server 2008  32 bit machine or not ?

On the other hand it works with 64 bit machine with apache-tomcat-8.5.40 installed. This issue is only observed in 32bit 2008, and I can see here the database connection is breaking. I tried catching the exception in catch block but it doesn't catch the exception and i am unable to come to conclusion. Below is the code.

try {
mLogger.log(CustomLogTraceLevel.DEDUPE_TRACE, "Inside db connection");

```
        DataSource ds = DBDataSource.getDataSource();


        if (ds == null)
            throw new Result("ERROR_COULDNOT_GET_DB_SOURCE");
        // get connection object from connection pool
        mConnection = (Connection) ds.getConnection();// the code breaks here and it is not getting catch in the catch block

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        mLogger.error(se);
        mLogger.log(CustomLogTraceLevel.DEDUPE_TRACE, "SQL Code: " + se.getErrorCode());
        mLogger.log(CustomLogTraceLevel.DEDUPE_TRACE, "SQL Code: " + se.getMessage());
        mLogger.log(CustomLogTraceLevel.DEDUPE_TRACE, "SQL Code: " + se.getSQLState());
        mLogger.log(CustomLogTraceLevel.DEDUPE_TRACE, "SQL Code: " + se.getStackTrace());


    } catch (Result r) {
        mLogger.log(CustomLogTraceLevel.DEDUPE_TRACE, "Caught result exception");
        throw new Result("ERROR_COULDNOT_GET_DB_CONNECTION", r);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        mLogger.log(CustomLogTraceLevel.DEDUPE_TRACE, "in the exception ex block");
        mLogger.error(ex);
        throw new Result("ERROR_COULDNOT_GET_DB_CONNECTION", ex.getMessage());
    } finally {

        mLogger.log(CustomLogTraceLevel.DEDUPE_TRACE, "In the finally block");
        mLogger.debug("Exiting getConnection.");
    }
    return mConnection;
}
```

Comment: In general the answer to your question is "yes". But in order for anyone to help you on your problem you should provide way more details on it.

Comment: @Selaron I added the more details to the question.

Comment: What's the expected and observed output of the code? Is there a stack trace in tomcat log files?